# MediatorLiveData.getValue().isEmpty() returns false after delete directly

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, android-architecture-components

How can I check if a table is empty knowing that **I'm not in the Activity** with a guaranteed or synchronized returned value??

Hey guys, I'm new to architecture components.
I having a very strange problem with MediatorLiveData..
all I need to do is to delete all values in a Room Entity using background service "AlarmManager" 
**and postValue(null) to the MediatorLiveData**,
 then I need to call refreshTables() which check if there is no data in the table it calls a webservice and inserts the values.

everything works fine but when I watched the calling of refreshTables() after the deleting, sometimes the condition getValue().isEmpty() returns false!!

**when this thing happens it leaves the table without data.**

I believe there is a delay in MediatorLiveData observing.

Notes:

1- I'm calling refreshTables() in a thread (executor) after the deleting,  of course, refreshTables() executes using its executor.

2- this fault happens almost every 20 times of working fine.

3- I tried to override onChange but an exception was thrown because it cannot  cast LiveData to LifeCycleOwner

4- TableEntity is just a Room Entity contains fields about a restaurant table

```
 //the constructor
  private DataRepository(AppDatabase database
 ) {
     this.mDatabase = database;
     executor = new AppExecutors();


     mObserableTables = new MediatorLiveData<>();

              mObserableTables.addSource(mDatabase.tableDao().loadAllTables(),
             tableEntities -> {
                 if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null)
                     mObserableTables.postValue(tableEntities);
             });
 }    

  private MediatorLiveData<List<TableEntity>> mObserableTables;

public void refereshTables()
{

    executor.networkIO().execute(()->
    {
        try {
            if(mObserableTables.getValue()==null || mObserableTables.getValue().isEmpty()) {//<-the problem

                List<TableEntity> tableEntities = new WebserviceCall().getTablesOnline();
                mDatabase.tableDao().insertOrReplaceAllTables(tableEntities);
            }
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),e.getMessage());

        }
    });
}

 public void refreshTablesForService()
{
    executor.diskIO().execute(()->
    {

            int deletedRows=mDatabase.tableDao().deleteAllTables();
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName()
                    ,"deleted rows from tables= "+String.valueOf(deletedRows));

            mObserableTables.postValue(null);
                refereshTables();


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question :)

after hours of deep digging, I discovered that nothing to do getValue().
the problem was in .postValue() method which is used UiThread to put the value in LiveData. this for sure requires adding a task to UI which may be delayed and checking the data before it finished this task leads to inconsistency.

even trying to load all data from the table was providing inconsistency information.
trying to removeSource() will do nothing about this problem too.

I managed to handle this issue by using "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables" query which gives me accurate information.

btw, adding "Thread.sleep(100)" before calling refereshTables(); fixes the problem but give a very bad user experience.

a fantastic explanation allowed me to figure this out is https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-architecture-component-livedata--cms-29317